# The image of any linearly independent set under whatever linear transformation is lineraly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Here's my proof:

Suppose $T \colon S \subset U \to V$ is linear map, and S is linearly independent (i.e, $S = \{s_1,\dots, s_m\}$ s.t. $\sum_{i=0}^m a_i s_i = 0 \implies a_i =0 \quad \forall 0 \leq i \leq m$).

Now, the image of T (AFAIK) is $T(S)$. Now, let $T(S) = T(0) = 0$. Then, given that $T(\sum_{i=0}^m a_i s_i) = 0 \iff \sum_{i=0}^m T(a_i s_i) = 0 \iff a_i\sum_{i=0}^m T(s_i) = 0$ because of linearity, and since $a_i = 0$ by hypothesis, we concluide that $T(S) = \{T(s_1),\dots,T(s_m)\}$ is linearly independent.

Are my definitions correct? Is there any mistakes somewhere?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The result you're trying to prove is false. (Think about the simplest linear map of them all, $x\mapsto 0$.)

Comment: if $T(S)=0$ then $T$ is the trivial map that Noah mentioned

Comment: Yes, that was something I thought about but didn't know how could it be proved. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hypothesis only says that $a_i=0$ if $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i s_i = 0$. But for a (general) linear map $T$, $T(v)$ can be zero even if $v \neq 0$. To make your argument work, you need $T$ to be injective so that $T(v)=0 \implies v=0$. And under this extra condition, $T(S)$ is indeed linearly independent.